# vb.net crystal report is asking for database login and password but logon failed

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm new in making crystal reports and I'm done creating my crystal report but when running my program it asks for my logon information but after I log in, it says that

> logon failed

I tried to look in other questions here in the site but I was not able to find an answer. My Visual Studio is 2013 Ultimate and my sql is sql-server 2014 express.

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim show As String = String.Empty
        show &= "select * from fruit_stock "
        show &= "where date_received=@daterec"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=WIN10;database=fruit_storage;user=fruit_admin;password=admin;")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand
                With cmd
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = show
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@daterec", TextBox1.Text)
                End With

                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd
                    da.Fill(ds, "fruit_stock")
                    Dim report As New CrystalReport1
                    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
                    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

                    conn.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: First I would not share any passwords here. Second, are you sure your connection string is correct ?

Comment: why its just an sql login and password. and yess it is correct

Comment: Also the use of AddWithValue is not a good idea, read this https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: what i really need is how to not show the login and password of my database everytime i run the code

Comment: If it asks you for login/pass than that means that either your connection string is not correct, or crystal report is using its own connection and does not uses your connectionstring

Comment: i have add a data set in my server explorer and it add my database in it.

Comment: Does your cystalreport uses the same connection ? That is what you should find out. My guess is your report has its own connection and the connection string is never set there

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim report As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
report.Load("<physical filename of your report>")
report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables("fruit_stock"))

<your_crystal_report_viewer_in_your_form>.ReportSource = report
```

if you are using an embedded report

```
Dim report As New <Name of your embedded crystal report>
report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables("fruit_stock"))

<your_crystal_report_viewer_in_your_form>.ReportSource = report
```